# Determining the sum of the product of all subsets of all sizes

Tags: binomial-theorem

Essentially, $$\sum_{I\subset[1,n]}\pi(I)$$ where $I\subset \mathbb{N}$ and $\pi(I)$ is the product of numbers in $I$

Comment: What have you tried? What's the source of problem?

Comment: I've tried it for the case of all the subsets of a particular size $k$.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646363/sum-of-products-of-elements-of-nonempty-subsets-of-a-set

Comment: Obviously general result is $(n+1)!+\ldots$

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the notation. Are all $I$ sequential as in $[1,2]$ and $[1,2,3]$ and so on or can $I$ be $[1,3,4]$?

Comment: The sum of the products is  $(n+1)!$

Comment: @Raffaele how do you get that?